# changing grep regex output

Tags: regex, bash, hadoop

How come with this command

with this command

`hadoop fs -ls -R /path/to/dir/d_20141123* | grep -oE '(.*)?\/(.*)\/'`

I get this output

```
-rw-r--r-- 2014-11-23 20:00 /path/to/dir/d_20141123-2301/
-rw-r--r-- 2014-11-23 20:00 /path/to/dir/d_20141123-2302/
-rw-r--r-- 2014-11-23 20:00 /path/to/dir/d_20141123-2303/
...
...
```

But with

`hadoop fs -ls -R /path/to/dir/d_20141123* | grep -oE '\/(d_.*)\/'`

I get an output of:

```
/d_423432-342/
/d_231314-343/
...
...
```

But with this command:

`hadoop fs -ls -R /path/to/dir/d_20141123* | grep -oE '(d_\d+\-\d+)'`

I get no output. Why is that? All I removed was the forward slashes in my regex

Comment: What does it have to do with `bash`? They all are `grep regex`, not `bash regex`

Answer (score 1):

> All I removed was the forward slashes in my regex

If only. You removed the forward slashes, you removed the backslashes escaping them, you removed the `.*`, and you added in `\d+\-\d+`.

Doing them one at a time, you'll find the problem: `grep -E` doesn't support `\d` as a synonym for `[[:digit:]]`.

Either rewrite to use `[[:digit:]]` (which is POSIX) or use `grep -P` (which is GNU):

```
grep -oE '(d_[[:digit:]]+-[[:digit:]]+)'
grep -oP '(d_\d+\-\d+)'
```

You can also simplify it in various ways depending on your expected input:

```
grep -oE 'd_[^/]*'
grep -oE 'd_[0-9-]*'
```